# Python - Change List Items

Tags: python

Initially, we have name and numbers inside list, it is necessary to convert all in new list

```
name1 = [u'pPlane1']
list1 = [19, 20, 21, 22, 24]
```

The desired result:

```
list2 = ['pPlane1.e[19]', 'pPlane1.e[20]', 'pPlane1.e[21]', 'pPlane1.e[22]', 'pPlane1.e[24]']
```

I would be grateful for any help :)

Comment: How should it look like for multiple names?

Comment: what if `name1 = [u'pPlane1', u'pPlane2']` or name1 is always 1-item list?

Comment: always 1-item list. weird, I know :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list2 = [name1[0]+'.e['+str(i)+']' for i in list1]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use list comprehension to create the new list directly from the source. By using string formatting, you can create the target string of each element nicely.

```
list2 = ['{}.e[{}]'.format(name1[0], num) for num in list1]
```

If `name1` contains multiple names, you could create a cartesian product like this:

```
list2 = ['{}.e[{}]'.format(name, num) for num in list1 for name in name1]
```

For example:

```
>>> name1 = ['pPlane1', 'pPlane2']
>>> list1 = [19, 20, 21]
>>> ['{}.e[{}]'.format(name, num) for num in list1 for name in name1]
['pPlane1.e[19]', 'pPlane2.e[19]', 'pPlane1.e[20]', 'pPlane2.e[20]', 'pPlane1.e[21]', 'pPlane2.e[21]']
```